# How to add a preprocessor definition in android globally

Tags: android

I want to add a pre-processor definition in my android project globally. So In android, I could add my modifications like this:

```
#ifdef VENDOR_EDIT
//zhiquan.huang@MMApp.Camera, 2013/07/11 add for hello module                                                                                                            
    register_android_server_HelloService(env); 
#endif/* VENDOR_EDIT */
```

I don't know where to add the `VENDOR_EDIT` macro in android build system, can anyone help me?
THX

Comment: do you need this only on one android app or the whole android open source project?

Comment: the whole android opensource project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your declaration to `COMMON_GLOBAL_CFLAGS` and `COMMON_GLOBAL_CPPFLAGS` in build/core/config.mk
So add below line in config.mk or device specific make file.

```
COMMON_GLOBAL_CFLAGS+=-DVENDOR_EDIT
COMMON_GLOBAL_CPPFLAGS+=-DVENDOR_EDIT
```

Comment: I found COMMON_GLOBAL_CFLAGS+=-DVENDOR_EDIT is already take effect for  frameworks/base/services/jni/onload.cpp   Is there some difference for COMMON_GLOBAL_CFLAGS and  COMMON_GLOBAL_CPPFLAGS? By the way, what can I do if I want to add some macro take effect in all java code?

Comment: CFLAGS is used while compiling .c files and CPPFLAGS is used for compiling .cpp files. What kind of macro are you talking about for java files

Comment: Oh, sorry. I misunderstood my code project.  @nandeesh, thank you